# Using Google App Engine and Firebase Cloud Messaging for notifications

Tags: android, google-app-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

Some of my overall questions:

1. How do you create a Node.js project on Google App Engine?
2. Is the right way to edit the project by opening Google Cloud Shell and going to File > Launch code editor?
3. How do you use Google App Engine to listen to Firebase?

Details:

So I know this has been asked many times before, but I've read and looked around and I'm still at a loss. Basically, there's a chat portion in my Android app that uses Firebase (works fine), but I want to send notifications when a user receives a message they haven't seen yet like most chat apps do.

Here's what I'm following for the notification portion (https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html). What I (think I) understand so far, but please correct me if I'm not getting this right:

- You put the notifications in a queue in Firebase
- You use a separate environment to listen to Firebase and send out the notifications
- You subscribe the users to a topic (in my case, an event)

My main question about this part is where in the world I'm supposed to put the Node code. I tried putting it where the Hello World code was, but I just got errors.

My second part is trying to figure out Google App Engine. I messed around with the built in Hello World tutorial, and I've managed to change the word "world" to something else. Other than that, I'm still pretty confused and I haven't been able to find a super broken down step-by-step tutorial for this. I don't know if I'm just using terrible keywords or what, but I can't even figure out how to create a new "project" in your Google Cloud Platform project.

Sorry if this is a lot of jumbled words. Basically I'm really confused lol. Even just an idea of where to start learning this information would be really helpful because my searches or keywords are turning up results that I just don't understand. Thank you!

Comment: As @cbradshaw answered: Cloud Functions are a great way to send notifications. In fact, sending notifications is the first [use-case in the Firebase documentation for Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases). :-)    If you'd prefer to use App Engine for this after all, see [this page on using App Engine Standard with Firebase](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio) and [this page on using App Engine Flex with Firebase](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-app-engine-flexible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just last week Google actually released a feature called Cloud Functions which sounds like it will handle your use case perfectly. It allows you to put your Node.js on Firebase and eliminates the need for you to setup a server in some cases. Using Firebase Functions you can have Realtime Database changes trigger a notification to be sent.

I suggest you read through all of the Firebase Functions documentation but this is what you will particularly be looking for: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events.

Comment: You are a godsend. This sounds perfect, thank you so, so much!